# What is the use of a public constructor in a private class

Tags: c#

I have the following class structure defined:

```
public sealed class PublicClass
{
    private PrivateClass privateClass;

    public PublicClass()
    {
        this.privateClass = new PrivateClass();
    }

    private sealed class PrivateClass
    {
        public PrivateClass()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it necessary to make the constructor of PrivateClass "public" or "internal" in order to construct an instance of PrivateClass in the the PublicClass's constructor? Using "protected" or "private" modifiers on the PrivateClass constructor throw a compilation error.

Comment: If the constructor was private you could never create the class from another class.  So  you can never start executing anything in the class.

Comment: Your question contains its own answer...you ask why the constructor is public, and then note that the code doesn't compile if it's private.  The constructor is public because the code wouldn't compile if it were private, exactly as you noted.

Comment: @jdweng But, you can.  It's a common enough pattern to have a private constructor with `public static` factory methods (or properties) to create/fetch instances of the class, or to have private constructors that are only ever called by other (less restrictively scoped) constructors.

Comment: Ok, you have to have at least one constructor that is public.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is it necessary to make the constructor of PrivateClass "public" or "internal" in order to construct an instance of PrivateClass in the the PublicClass's constructor?

The PrivateClass is a nested class of the PublicClass, so the PublicClass has access to it just like any other field, property or method. And just like an `object` property or field, the access modifiers on the object's ctor, properties and methods are applicable to the PublicClass's access.

```
public sealed class PublicClass
{
    // this is private, but public class has access to it
    private PrivateClass privateClass;

    public PublicClass()
    {
      // can't be called, privateClass's ctor/method is private
      // privateClass = newPrivateClass();

      // can be called, this static method is public
      privateClass = PrivateClass.GetInstance();

      // can't be called, it's private
      // privateClass.DoWork();
    }

    // this is private, but public class has access to it
    private sealed class PrivateClass
    {

        private PrivateClass()
        {
        }

        public static PrivateClass GetInstance()
        {
          // can be called within the class itself, it has
          // access to private's (method, fields, properties, ctors)
          return new PrivateClass();
        }

        private void DoWork() { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you cannot mark it as protected because you use `sealed` - that means nobody can inherit from this class. To be able to create an instance of a class in this namespace you should use public or internal. You are not able to create this class in other namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Because although the type is private and only available to the class it is contained in if you make the constructor private even the containing class could not call it (*without using reflection*).

Answer (score 0):

In adition to the other answers I think is good to remark this about private constructors:

> A private constructor is a special instance constructor. It is
>   generally used in classes that contain static members only. If a class
>   has one or more private constructors and no public constructors, other
>   classes (except nested classes) cannot create instances of this class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcfb85a6.aspx